# How to return a specific value from the database on View from Controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller, laravel-views

I am trying to return a specific value from the database on View(activate_id) from `AdminController` but it returns nothing.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/activate-id', 'AdminController@activateId')->middleware('role:admin');
```

**AdminController.php**

```
public function activateId(Request $request)
{
    $by = DB::table('users')
        ->select('referrer')
        ->where('username', $request->username)
        ->first();

    return view('activate_id')->with('by', $by);
}
```

**activate_id.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="/activate-user">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="fuser" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <p class="text-info" id="fdetails"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Referrer</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="by" id="recipient-name" value="{{$by}}" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success"> Activate</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Does `dd($by);` show the expected result in your controller before returning the view? You may need to do `{{ $by->referrer }}` in your blade file.

Comment: After {{ $by->referrer }} adding this it returns
Arguments
"Trying to get property 'referrer' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mlm-solution-master\resources\views\activate_id.blade.php)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result that comes out from the database is object, which in your case is $by variable, so you need to extract the value of referrer from it.

So to solve the problem try this:

```
 {{$by->referrer}}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Arguments
"Trying to get property 'referrer' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mlm-solution-master\resources\views\activate_id.blade.php)"

Comment: Can you please var_dump the value of $by in the controller before you send to the view.

Comment: It returns NULL 
public function activateId(Request $request)
    {
        

        $by = DB::table('users')->select('referrer')->where('username', $request->username)->first();

       
        var_dump($by);
        die();
        return view('activate_id')->with('by', $by);
    }

Comment: Then the problem is in your query, try to fix it, possible cause is the value of the username that comes from the request.

Comment: thanks, you are correct @Hardood that was my silly mistake...